# C++ design : Design to support Unicode msg as well as ASCII msg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, oop, unicode

Currently my code have `CString DisplayMessage`, which is being used by my code all over to exchange `DisplayMessage` between clients and servers. Now as software is going international, I want `DisplayMessage` to have Unicode string message.

One technique I found is to

1. Create:

   ```
   Class CDisplayMessage{
          CString ASCIIMsg;
          CStringW UnicodeMsg;
          bool IsUnicode;
          ...
   };
   ```

   ASCII msg is required, So that I can make message backward compatible.
2. Replace data type of `CString DisplayMessage` to `CDisplayMessage DisplayMessage`.
3. And then need to change all the places where it is being used (that is more headache). Usage is like:

   ```
   DisplayMessage = some other CString;

   DisplayMessage = "sdfsdf";
   ```

**Question:**

Can anyone suggest me to provide some other solution or improve my solution, so that their is minimum change to do at all other places.

**Note:**

- Platform : MS VISUAL STUDIO (Windows), C++
- CharSet: Multi-Byte Character Set(can't change)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `CStringW` and convert to `CStringA` if necessary. Please note that CString depends on `_UNICODE` settings. So it compiles to `CStringW` if **UNICODE** is defined and to `CStringA` in case of **MBCS**.

The conversion is real simple:

```
CStringW sTestW( L"Test" );
CStringA sTestA( "Test" );

// ASCII <-> UTF16
CStringW sConvertW = sTestA;
CStringA sConvertA = sTestW;

// UTF16 <-> UTF8
CStringA CUtility::UTF16toUTF8(const CStringW& utf16)
{
    return CW2A(utf16, CP_UTF8);
}

CStringW CUtility::UTF8toUTF16(const CStringA& utf8)
{
    return CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8);
}
```

Comment: Thank for the solution Andrew, But UNICODE macro is my restriction as I mentioned that my project is Multi-byte charset and I can not cange it to UNICODE charset.
Secondly I want to use a variable that can take both kind of values ASCII as well as UNICODE, because some systems are still using ASCII. So I need to preserve both.

Comment: That's fine. You can use CStringA and CStringW anyways in MBCS. So basically the solution remains the same for both UNICODE and MBCS builds.

Comment: If I change to CStringW then It can not accept ASCII msg. I want to use a variable that can take both kind of values ASCII as well as UNICODE, because some systems are still using ASCII. So I need to preserve both.

Comment: sure you can simply assign your CStringW to ASCII string. it will convert it internally to UTF16. The UNICODE charset is much wider than ASCII. So it is totally safe. See my examples. Please provide real scenario (code snippet) to demonstrate how you going to use it. So far I don't see any problems sticking with just CStringW.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.
but Still I have one query. Suppose I have Unicoded msg in 
`CStringW dispmsg` . 
Now If I want to convert this Unicoded msg to ASCII. Is there any way to do this ? Assume that msg is of English alphabets only.

Comment: sure: CStringA asciiStr = dispmsg; That's it. FYI: In MBCS CString and CStringA are exactly the same.